Add numbers in a object within a JavasScript array from an index below a value and return value
What is the best way to return the sum of an array from a certain index that matches a criteria.
For example, I want to find the sum of each array from index 1 with values less than or equal to 4;
a = [];
    
a[0] = {};
a[0].age = [3,4,8,12,1];
a[0].result = 0;
    
a[1] = {};
a[1].age = [5,1,3,2,10,12];
a[1].result = 0;

// Formula should return a[0].result = 5; a[1].result = 6;

I know I can loop over each array but wondered if there was a more suitable way as ultimately there will be a lot more arrays;

You'll have to look at each list value from the given index onwards. So looping, explicitly or not, will be needed. Thus the question for "a more suitable way" than looping is based on a misunderstanding.

I would write a function that starts by slicing the array based on the index you want to start at, then filter that based on the values, finally use reduce to find the sum.

But a simple for loop will probably be clearer.

Please consider changing "What is the best way" to focus on a specific concern. Is the goal legibility? Execution time? Memory utilization?

You can achieve the required result in the following way:


const a = [{age:[3,4,8,12,1],result:0},
           {age:[5,1,3,2,10,12],result:0}];

a.forEach(e=>e.result=e.age.slice(1).reduce((sum,c)=>sum+(c<=4?c:0),0));

console.log(a);



As an initialised result property does already exist in each object (with the value 0) you could even substitute the .reduce() by a simpler .forEach() call:


const a = [{age:[3,4,8,12,1],result:0},
           {age:[5,1,3,2,10,12],result:0}];

a.forEach(e=>e.age.forEach((c,i)=>{if(i&&c<=4)e.result+=c}));

console.log(a);



And, as @DM suggested, I am now avoiding the slice() call and replacing it with a test on the inner index i.

Well, yes, I could. But I am not really reallocating the array. I am simply "taking a part of it", starting at index 1 and I am using it to sum up the elements smaller or equal to 4.

You can simply get an index from the user and comparison number and run for loop on an array. I am providing hard-coded comparisonNumber and indexNumber
let indexNumber = 0;
let comparisonNumber = 6;
let count = 0;

let array = [1, 7, 2, 3, 12];

for (let i = indexNumber; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < comparisonNumber) {
        count+= array[I];
    } 
}

console.log(count);

